# Help with iPhone In-App purchase

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

We want to sell digital content through subscription model in our app. Is it possible to support a subscription bundle? Let's say content in question is magazine subscription for $0.99 a month. Is it possible to support a bundle of subscription such that user can subscribe to any three magazine by buying a bundle for let's say $1.99? Or is it possible to support eat-all-you-can model - $3.99 for subscribing to all magazines in our app?

Answer (score 1):

According to the official documents from Apple, yes you can. What you need to do is design your iAP store and items according to Apple's requirements.

> Getting Started with In App Purchase
>   on iPhone OS (Version 2.0)
>
> ...
>
> Subscriptions
>
> Subscriptions and subscription
>   renewals to content or services can be
>   offered to customers for purchase. You
>   can offer customers the opportunity to
>   renew their content or service
>   subscriptions using In App Purchase,
>   but be sure to define a reasonable
>   renewal frequency to avoid bothering
>   users with unwelcome reminders. Be
>   aware that you are responsible for
>   both tracking subscription expirations
>   and for renewal billing; the App Store
>   does not monitor subscription duration
>   and does not offer an automatic
>   billing mechanism. Be sure to indicate
>   when an item is a subscription when
>   entering its product information into
>   iTunes Connect.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I understand that in App purchase supports subscriptions. But what I am looking for is bundling of subscriptions. Let's say we have 5 different catalog items. A user can buy subscriptions to any of these 5 items individually. Additionally, can we also sell a bundled subscription to 3 of those 5 items? By subscribing to the bundle, user can choose any 3 items from the listed 5 items?

Comment: @Rajat: I think it's achievable as long as you describe them in a succinct and clear way to the Apple Review Team and your app users. I would suggest you make each of those subscription bundles a standalone **iAP subscription item**, and price them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these features are supported, they are called consumable and non-consumable in-app purchases.